# Why I get 'can't assign to operator' error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, label-encoding

When I try to assign `LabelEncoder()` to `label_encoder`, I get an error:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

However, I assigned `LabelEncoder()` to `label_encoder` in the past.
Here is my code:

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
play-label = label_encoder.fit_transform(play)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `play-label` is written correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue related to assigning value to a variable. This is a `Syntax Error`. You haven't followed the proper naming convention to name the variable `play-label`.

If you try doing something like this :

```
>>> a-b = 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

You'll get the same error.
Replace dash `-` with Underscore `_` and it will work fine.
The correct variable name should be `play_label`.
Refer to this link, for an indepth description . [Python Naming Convention](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/180/lectures/W02/lec2/VariableNamingConvetions.html)

Answer (score 1):

It should be **play_label** not **play-label**. You have used the **"-"** on a variable which is an operator.